# If image = null, do nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got some code getting data from a database. 
Sometimes, there is also an image among that data which i fetch like this:

```
<img src="@Model.Pictue.Url">
```

The problem is that an image does not always exist in the DB which generates a null-exception.
Can I maybe create an if-statement checking if there is an image and if its not, step-over the image-part?

Or is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this:

```
@if(Model.Picture != null)
{

<img src="@Model.Pictue.Url">
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ehsan! You saved me again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@if(Model.Picture != null)
{
<img src="@Model.Pictue.Url">
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..You can put dummy picture if you dont have

```
@if(Model.Picture.Url == null)
{    
   <img src="/DummyPicture">
}
else
{
   <img src="@Model.Pictue.Url">
}
```